# JavaScript - Drag Image - max. 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a javascript script that makes it possible to drag 3 images into another div. once the user dragged 3 images on the box, it can't drag another image to the box,

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qvmwgf5p/1/

As you can see, it allows user to drag all images to the div, and I want to make it a lock on 3.

Thanks forwards ;')

```
$(function () {
    $(".cards img").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        refreshPositions: true,
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
            var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
            if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {

            }
            else {
                alert(" Sleep de kaart naar de box, Dat is er naast.. drunk.");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#dvDest").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($("#dvDest img").length == 3) {
                    alert(" DEBUG: Selected 3 cards -> Now we have to flip them");
           //     $("#dvDest").html("");  dit zorgt ervoor dat me kaarten verdwijnen, appart:p
            }
              if ($("#dvDest img").length == 4) {
                    alert(" DEBUG: Wow dude, relax... The limit is 3 cards. 4 is not possible, fix this");
           //     $("#dvDest").html("");  dit zorgt ervoor dat me kaarten verdwijnen, appart:p
            }
            ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
            $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem:
for the one with the same issue as I did, here is the fix:

```
 drag: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
             if ($("#dvDest img").length == 3) {return false;}
```

This: `if ($("#dvDest img").length == 3) {return false;}`